# How to assign an anonymous function from a JS file

Tags: javascript

hope everyone will be doing good.

I am working on a project, which uses fabric.js, and I have a JS file that looks like this:

```
(function(){
    this.foo = 'bar';
    this.bar = 'foo';
    ...........
    ...........
    ...........
    ...........
})();
```

Now, if I want to store the result of the above script to a global variable, how can I achieve this?
I want this:

```
window.xyz = (function(){
    this.foo = 'bar';
    this.bar = 'foo';
    ...........
    ...........
    ...........
    ...........
})();
```

But, as I have said that this code is in a separate JS file, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Does the IIFE return anything? If so, then the result is discarded, if it’s in a separate file.

Comment: The contents you've shown of that IIFE are a but suspect. It's assigning to `this.foo` and `this.bar`, but `this` within that call will either be `undefined` (in strict mode) or a reference to the global object (in loose mode).

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly do what you've said you want to do unless you can change the other file so that it either puts the result in a global for you or exports its result, etc.

The *indirect* way you can do it is by reading the file as a string, adding `return`  at the beginning of the string, and converting it to code via `new Function`:

```
window.xyz = new Function("return " + theFileContents)();
```

I **do not recommend this** unless you can absolutely trust the contents of the file (the same way you'd trust a file you loaded via `import` or `require`). If you can trust it, this works, but it's a workaround.

The real solution is to modify the other file.

---

You've said this is in a browser. That means you can use [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) to load the other file:

```
fetch("./the-other-file.js")
.then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error ${response.status}`);
    }
    return response.text();
})
.then(code => {
    window.xyz = new Function("return " + code)();
})
.catch(error => {
    // ...handle/report error...
});
```

That's trusting the content of that file as much as `<script src="./the-other-file.js"></script>` in your HTML would be.

Comment: @TalhaQuddoos - That depends on the environment you're in. Have you looked into how to read files as strings in your environment?

Comment: I'm in front-end environment, so I'm not sure if I can read a file.

Comment: @TalhaQuddoos - If by front-end you mean a browser, yes, you can read files from the same origin (or any other origin that passlists the origin of the page you're doing this from via CORS) using [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch).